# Remove duplicates from nested map objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I'm displaying data on a grid using a nested map which looks like

```
{
    this.state.rows.map((qc) =>
        qc.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs.map((qc2) =>
            qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.map((qc3) =>
              {console.log("results", qc3.Defect)}
                <div className="row table">
                    {qc3.Defect}
                </div>
            )
        )
    )
}
```

Which returns data that looks like this

`results Scuff
results Sunburn
results Bruise
results Hail damage
results Scuff
results Sunburn
results Bruise
results Scuff
results Sunburn
results Hail damage`

How to get rid of the duplicates? I have tried

`{console.log("unique",[...new Set(qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.map((qc3) => qc3.Defect))])}`

but that returns each iteration of the mapped object

Comment: Can you show actual data? `this.state.rows`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way is that create an array in which you push the elements that are printed.And before printing the other check if its present in array or not.

```
const arr = [];
{
    this.state.rows.map((qc) =>
        qc.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs.map((qc2) =>
            qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.map((qc3) =>
              {!arr.includes(qc3.Defect) && arr.push(qc3.Defect) &&
                (<div className="row table">
                    {qc3.Defect}
                </div>)
              }
            ) 
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: When using {console.log("testing", qc3.Defect)} I can see the desired result, however, nothing is actually being rendered...